# Foundation 5 Not detecting mobile resolution

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I created a simple website: http://mpl.mediatech.co.in using Foundation 5, and it works ok on Desktop / Firefox Responsive Design View:

[image]
[image]

but on the iphone / android phones, it looks like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had missed out on adding this important meta tag...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

That fixed it. Leaving the question up in case someone else does the same mistake.